# Why is homology $0$ here? $H(\vartriangle,A) = 0$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> [image]

In the remark, it says the homology is $0$. I deduced that $$H_i(\vartriangle,A) = \frac{\ker(d_{-1})}{\operatorname{im}(d_0)} = \ker(d_{-1})$$ because $\operatorname{im}(d_0) = 0$. But why is $\epsilon$ injective? It is only a surjective homomorphism right?

Comment: Be careful, your calculation references (standard) homology, while the text is referencing reduced homology.  The difference at $\widetilde{H}_0$ changes the formulas slightly.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, so $\epsilon$ is the $0$ map? I think is the difference?

Comment: Yes, that is the only difference, but then you have the wrong maps in your homology calculation...

Comment: @MichaelBurr, what wrong maps? We just know that $d_{-1} : C_{-1} \to 0$ now and $ker(d_{-1}) = 0 $ because $0: C_0 \to C_{-1}$

Comment: $d_0$ should be replaced by the $\varepsilon$ map.  You are not reasoning about the original $d_0$ map (which is just the $0$ map), but the new $\varepsilon$ map.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, isn't this just an labelling problem? But everything else I deduced is right? $H_i =  ker(d_{-1})/Im(0) = ker(d_{-1}) = 0$ by my previous reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is incorrect.  In order to get $\widetilde{H}_{-1}$ to be $0$, you don't need $im(d_0)$ to be $0$, you need $im(d_0)=ker(d_{-1})$.

The kernel of the $d_{-1}$ map is all of $A$.  The image of the $\varepsilon$ map is also all of $A$.  Therefore, the quotient is trivial.

You should be careful about writing $d_0$ because $d_0$ is a map used in a different type of homology and is a different map.  In (regular) homology, $d_0$ would be the zero map.  Here, the map at the $0$-th level of the chain is *not* the zero map, it is the $\varepsilon$ map which is surjective.  Note that $im(\varepsilon)=0$ does *not* mean that $\varepsilon=0$.

For (regular) homology, you would have $ker(d_{-1})/im(d_0)=0$ because $C_{-1}=0$, whereas in reduced homology $C_{-1}\not=0$, so there is more work to do.

Comment: Well, it's only a coincidence that $d_0$ is the $0$ map though?

Comment: Unfortunately, your reasoning is not correct, I tried to highlight the errors/confusions in my edits.